# JPA ManyToMany mapping with additional fields

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have a next three tables (PostgreSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE boards (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ....
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cards (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(256),
    description TEXT,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS boards_cards(
    board_id INTEGER,
    card_id INTEGER,
    on_hold BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    CONSTRAINT pk_user_card PRIMARY KEY (board_id, card_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(board_id) REFERENCES boards(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(card_id) REFERENCES cards(id)
);
```

and a following JPA entites:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "boards")
public class Board extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "boards_id_seq", sequenceName = "boards_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "boards_id_seq")
    private Long id;


@Entity
@Table(name = "cards")
public class Card extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cards_id_seq", sequenceName = "cards_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "cards_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;
```

How to properly organize mappings in order to be able to get `boards_cards.on_hold` for a certain `Card` that is mapped to `Board` via `ManyToMany` relationship over `boards_cards` table ?

Comment: chceck this out http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: marginally related but using IDENTITY sequence generator works in pg and makes things easier

Comment: @Niel-McGuigan Identity doesn't allow for preallocation and has other draw backs - how does it make thing easier?  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Identity_sequencing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a relational table with extra columns, and the question comes up frequently so you should be able to find many other answers, examples and tutorials with a search.

I believe the best solution though is to map the relation table as an entity, giving you complete control over the fields and data.  You then can map it how ever you need to fit into your model, and even hide its existence from the model if needed.  For instance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "boards_cards")
public class Board_Card extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  Board board;
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  Card card;
  Boolean on_hold;
}
```

This can then be referenced in your Card and Board entity how ever is needed.  One option might be to hide Card_Board entities, and only return Card entities:

```
public class Board extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
  ..
  @OneToMany(mappedby="board")
  List<Card_Board> card_board_list;
  @Transient
  List<Card> cards;

  public List<Card> getCards(){
    if (cards ==null) {
      cards=new ArrayList();
      for (Card_Board cb: card_board_list) {
        cards.add(cb.getCard());
      }
    }
    return cards;
  }
```

You can break up the list into two separate lists: an on_hold list and an active list.